# Model binding error with custom property getter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have getting an error during the model bind when I use try to bind a model with these two properties:

```
    private IEnumerable<Claimant> _drivers;
    public IEnumerable<Claimant> Drivers
    {
        get
        {
            return _drivers ?? Enumerable.Empty<Claimant>();
        }
        set
        {
            _drivers = value;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Property> _vehicles;
    public IEnumerable<Property> Vehicles
    {
        get
        {
            return _vehicles ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>();
        }
        set
        {
            _vehicles = value;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       <snip>
  InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
       Message=Collection is read-only.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.SZArrayHelper.Clear[T]()
            at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CollectionHelpers
                         .ReplaceCollectionImpl[T](ICollection`1 collection, IEnumerable newContents)
       InnerException:
```

If I change the properties to basic auto properties:

```
    public IEnumerable<Claimant> Drivers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Property> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

Everything works fine.

Why would the model binding have issues when the setters are the same as the auto property setters?

***Edit*** - Reading through the [default model binder source](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77537#266460) eventually leads you to this, where the first line is calling `Clear()` against the property, so when I returned the `Empty<T>` it obviously is not going to work.

```
private static void ReplaceCollectionImpl<T>(ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable newContents) 
{
    collection.Clear();
    if (newContents != null) 
    {
        foreach (object item in newContents) 
        {
            // if the item was not a T, some conversion failed. the error message will be propagated,
            // but in the meanwhile we need to make a placeholder element in the array.
            T castItem = (item is T) ? (T)item : default(T);
            collection.Add(castItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
get 
{
    return _drivers ?? new List<Claimant>();
}
```

Comment: This corrects the error, it's just the whole thing seems strange to me. I suppose I'm going to have to dig into the default binder source code to see what exactly it's doing here.

Comment: The collection returned by the property must be dynamic, not static readonly array because the model binder attempts to resize it.

Comment: Had a similar problem, I checked whether methods were public and for special method attributes though it was a simple as changing `Enumerable.Empty<MyType>()` to `new List<MyType>()`. Cheers @DarinDimitrov!

Answer (score 6):

IIRC `Enumerable.Empty<T>` is a static, read-only enumerable used to pass an empty storage-agnostic enumerable to  methods.  It is not meant to be used as a "starting point" for an empty collection.  That is likely why you're getting the error.

Choose a storage mechanism (e.g. `List<T>`) and use that as the type for your backing field.  You can then either initialize it

1. in the class definition,
2. in the constructor, or
3. at first get:

examples:

```
private List<Claimant> _drivers = new List<Claimamt>();  // Option 1

public MyModel()
{
    _drivers = new List<Claimant>();   // Option 2
}

public IEnumerable<Claimant> Drivers
{
    get
    {
        return _drivers ?? (_drivers = new List<Claimant>()); // Option 3
    }
    set
    {
        _drivers = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, I have also run into this issue when defaulting an array to an empty array (rather than null). The solution would be to set the array to null, or create a new model binder, as shown here (though I haven't tried either solution yet): http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/better-array-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

In a custom getter, I have typically seen the null coalescing operator (??) used to set the private backing field upon returning:

```
private IEnumerable<Claimant> _drivers;
public IEnumerable<Claimant> Drivers
{
    get
    {
        return _drivers ?? (_drivers = Enumerable.Empty<Claimant>());
    }
    set
    {
        _drivers = value;
    }
}
```

You could also try to set the default value to an empty array:

```
(_drivers = new Claimant[]{})
```

Answer (score 1):

Find out the exact property name and type causing the problem:

```
public class TestBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(bindingContext.ModelName);
        Debug.WriteLine(bindingContext.ModelType.ToString());

        //HOW TO USE: Look at your Output for the most recently output ModelName and Type to determine where there problem lies

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Set this binder as the default:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new TestBinder();
```